# Load js asynchronously in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript

I have tried to **load js asynchronously** in **Magento 2** following a recommendation from the Google PageSpeed Insights tool. Unfortunately my updates in the relevant layout file break the page.

**CURRENT LAYOUT XML**

```
<head>
 <script async src="js::myown.js"/>
 <script async src="js::another.js"/>
 <script async src="js::afinal.js"/>
</head>
```

Can someone please recommend a solution to the above to get the async loading working?

Comment: I recommend looking at using require.js to add your scripts, [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/) is a good article explaining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attribute async="async" between script tag

```
<script async="async" src="Vendor_ModuleName::js/your.own.js"/>
```

or in theme

```
<script async="async" src="js/your.own.js"/>
```